# how to detect a double on a single click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a click event how to know this a double click. If it's a click, I want return; But how can to know it's a double click?

```html
<hr style="clear:both; width:100%;" />
<p id="testClick">Click here</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testClick").click(function () {
            //if double click: console.log("2"); and return 
            //else
            // do some thing
            console.log("1");
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is basically correct, but it's a little more complicated than that

```html
<hr style="clear:both; width:100%;" />
<p id="testClick">Click here</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isDoubleClick = false;

    $("#testClick").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(!isDoubleClick) {
                console.log("1");
            }
        }, 500);
    });

    $("#testClick").dblclick(function () {
        console.log("2");
        isDoubleClick = true;

        setTimeout(function() {
            isDoubleClick = false;
        }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

If you don't want to use the dblclick handler for whatever reason, use numClicks++ instead of the boolean.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know from within a single click handler. You would have to build a custom logic like in this answer: [how to detect a double on a single click in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935150/how-to-detect-a-double-on-a-single-click-in-jquery/47935172?noredirect=1#comment82839822_47935172)

I suggest you listen to both events and build your logic around that. If you only need to know about double clicks, don't listen to single clicks.

Use the [dblclick](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) event handler:

```html
<hr style="clear:both; width:100%;" />
<p id="testClick">Click here</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testClick").click(function () {
            console.log("click"); // Here do nothing !
        });
        $("#testClick").dblclick(function () {
            console.log("double click");
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: you were few seconds faster! nice one

Comment: I know this way? but you can see, when you double click on your answer it log: "click double click", I expect result  from on.click(function (){}) how to know this is a single click or double click?. thanks for answer

Comment: There is no way to know, you would have to use setTimeout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935150/how-to-detect-a-double-on-a-single-click-in-jquery/47935172?noredirect=1#comment82839822_47935172

Comment: If you don't want to do anything for single clicks, just don't listen to that event